# Using LIKE or CONTAINS in a CASE Statement while using in, is it possible?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'm trying to update a gaming database and I'm stuck at a certain point.

It's missing all the values that have plural versions.

instead of having to go through the database and seeing which values were missed and adding them to the SQL is there a way to catch them all in the script?

I went through and tried to add LIKE and it seems you cannot have IN and LIKE in the same statement (from what I've tried) and I've also tried to use LEFT(family, 4) and that didn't work.

I would hate to have a massive script using AND and OR statements for each of the values.

Any help would be great.

```
UPDATE monster
SET ecosystem =

( CASE 
WHEN family in ('Behemoth', 'Buffalo', 'Cehuetzi', 'Cerberus', 'Coeurl', 'Dhalmel', 'Gnole', 'Manticore', 'Marid', 'Opo-opo', 'Raaz', 'Rabbit', 'Ram', 'Sheep', 'Tiger', 'Yztarg') THEN 'Beast' 
WHEN family in ('Adamantoise', 'Bugard', 'Eft', 'Gabbrath', 'Hill', 'Lizard', 'Matamata', 'Peiste', 'Raptor', 'Wivre') THEN 'Lizard' 
WHEN family in ('Antlion','Bee','Bees','Beetle','Bztavian','Chapuli','Chigoe','Crawler','Diremite','Fly','Flies','Gnat','Ladybug','Mantid','Mosquito','Scorpion','Spider','Twitherym','Wamoura','Wamouracampa') THEN 'Vermin' 
WHEN family in ('Belladonna','Flytrap','Funguar','Goobbue','Leafkin','Mandragora','Morbol','Panopt','Panopts','Rafflesia','Sabotender','Sapling','Snapweed','Treant','Yggdreant') THEN 'Plantoid' 
WHEN family in ('Acuex','Botulus','Flan','Hecteyes','Leech','Plovid','Sandworm','Slime','Slug','Worm') THEN 'Amorph' 
WHEN family in ('Amphiptere','Apkallu','Bat','Cockatrice','Colibri','Flock Bat','Greater Bird','Harpeia','Hippogryph','Lesser Bird','Tulfaires','Waktza') THEN 'Bird'
WHEN family in ('Crab','Craklaw','Frog','Orobon','Pteraketos','Pugil','Rockfin','Sea Monk','Ruszor','Uragnite') THEN 'Aquan'
WHEN family in ('Corpselight','Corse','Doomed','Dullahan','Fomor','Ghost','Hound','Naraka','Qutrub','Skeleton','Vampyr') THEN 'Undead'
WHEN family in ('Acrolith','Bomb','Bombs','Cardian','Caturae','Cluster','Detector','Doll','Evil Weapon','Golem','Grimoire','Iron Giant','Khimaira','Magic Pot','Marolith','Mimic','Snoll') THEN 'Arcana'
WHEN family in ('Ahriman','Defiant','Demon','Demons','Dvergr','Gallu','Gargouille','Imp','Macuil','Soulflayer','Taurus') THEN 'Demon'
WHEN family in ('Dragon','Hydra','Puk','Wyrm','Wyvern','Wyverns','Wyvern (Dragoon Pet)','Pet Wyvern','Pet Wyvers','Zilant') THEN 'Dragon'
END);
```

Comment: Looks like a job for a `LEFT JOIN` on a table that doesn't yet exist, but should.

Comment: @JeroenMostert the table exists, unless you are saying create a new table to add that column

Comment: make a table with with twio columns f.e Behemoth beast .... and join it to master, the name is promary key,. so that you don't have double names in it and if you haven't a family the row has there NULL, that you can join and update

Answer (score 0):

I ended up cleaning up the datasource

```
UPDATE monster
SET family = RTRIM(Family, '%s');
```

once I did this, it was very small cleaning..  Thanks for any replies.

Comment: I hope your solution is to have a family table, where each family occurs just once (in its singular form rather than both singular and plural) and have a proper foreign key constraint from monster to family, remove the ecosystem column from the monster table and add the ecosystem column to the family table. Because obviously every monster in a family shall belong to the same ecosystem.

Comment: And removing one s solved it all? Wouldn't the plurals of Acuex and Taurus be Acuexes and Tauruses rather than Acuexs and Tauruss?